# Hash Efficiency with tons of data

Tags: perl

I have data like this:

```
1 10
1 30
1 40
1 10
2 20
2 20
2 30
3 50
3 10
3 10
3 10
4 20
4 10
```

I would like to sum all the values up IF the value of first column matches, the result would be like this,

```
1 90
2 70
3 80
4 30
```

I have my code here,

```
while (<DATA>) 
{
my ($a, $b) = split;
$hash{$a}  += $b;
}

foreach $a (sort keys %hash) 
{
$b = $hash{$a};
print OUT "$a $b\n";
}
```

It works with sample data (around 100MB) but it seems to take ages to deal with my real data (around 100G). Are there any ways to optimize my codes?

Appreciate any advises in advance!

Comment: sounds like a good candidate for MapReduce. You could also look into using Threads.

Comment: Define "ages".  Where is this data coming from?  If it's from a hard disk, 100GB is going to take many many minutes to run, regardless of the processing that you're doing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it is from a hard disk..

Comment: Unless you have so many keys that your memory footprint starts causing thrashing of the program, you can't improve on this code much. Perl hashes are pretty efficient. Your best bet is getting the data split up into chunks, and reading/processing chunks in parallel using multiple separate disks/IO channels.

Comment: try the simple `time cat datafile >/dev/null` will get the minimum time for reading the file sequentially...

Comment: @DVK I am afraid it does have so many keys due to the file size (100G), so in that case waiting for ages is the only way? :(

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: It looks like the problem here is IO.  I don't think threads or MapReduce are going to help (unless the data source is split across the nodes).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That is the whole point of map reduce. Each chunk of data would be local to a node.

Comment: how many unique first column values are there, Sam?

Comment: or, equivalently, about how many total lines, and how many lines on average have the same first column value?

Comment: @ysth it should be more than 200 million unique first column values from the huge file...

Comment: @Sam: so are these 9 or so digit numbers? or strings?  how long are they, on average and longest?

Comment: @ysth thanks for your continuous focus on my issue. Actually the first column contains three  factors (ID, Date, Time) in the real data, the length for the combined first column is the same (25, including blanks between factors). I consider all of them as a hash key in order to speed up the processing time, but still think it needs to speed up...

Answer (score 3):

As others stated, your most likely bottleneck isn't hashes or Perl, but disk access.

Split up the file into smaller chunks. (using standard Unix utils if you can).

Store them on SEPARATE IO sources (different disks ideally on different controllers, ideally on different PCs).

- If you have only a few keys (e.g. >100-1000 rows per key), simply run chunks separately, then concatenate them all into 100x smaller file, and process that one file as a whole.
- Otherwise, synchronize the processing using a database to store sums.

Comment: thanks and i think i will try to use a database due to the number of keys. Anyway splitting up the file is a good try!

Comment: Trust DVK! Sort the chunks (files) with unix tools and sum the values until the key changes. Write the result to a new file. You can mangage tons of data with it. (also works when you have multiple keys)

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are quite efficient. They are probably the best solution to your problem. However, there could be exceptions, depending on your data:

- If all keys are integers in a (more or less) continuous range, then you can use an array instead, which is even more efficient than a hash:

  ```
  while (<DATA>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split;
    $array[$k] += $v;
  }

  for my $i (grep defined $array[$_], 0 .. $#array) {
    print "$i $array[$i]\n";
  }
  ```
- If the keys are already sorted, we don't need any intermediate data structure. Just accumulate the sum into a scalar. When the key changes, output the sum of the last key.
- If you have multiple files, you can apply your algorithm for each of these files in parallel and combine the results. This lets your code run in logarithmic time instead of linear time (aka. a big win). Either split the large file into smaller chunks, our do some magic with `seek` and `tell` to partition the file. The more busy processors you have, the faster your file will be summarized. **With one caveat:** It might very well be that I/O is your bottleneck. If this task has to be done regulary, using a SSD (instead of a HDD) might drastically improve performance.

Comment: thanks! using an array is more efficiency when the keys are in a continuous range. Anyway if the keys are not continuous, any efficient ideas using hash?

Comment: @Sam The “problem” with arrays is, that they are compact: If you have a key `1` and a key `1000`, there will be 999 allocated, but empty fields (all indices in between, plus zero). If the possible keys are low enough (where low depends on how important memory is for you), then an array is OK. For this use case, I'd get uncomfortable if any key exceeds `2E6` (two million).

Answer (score 1):

If your data looks like you show us it seems you have it sorted by key so hash is not necessary at all.

```
perl -anE'if($k!=$F[0]){say"$k $s"if$.>1;$k=$F[$s=0]}$s+=$F[1]}{say"$k $s"'
```

will do the trick. I doubt it will be slow.